# wp_insert_post with advanced custum fields repeater

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, wp-insert-post

at the moment i stuck a little bit at my new wordpress project.

The basics are: The user can create nutrition plans and there he can add some recipes, so i need to build a relationship from user > nutrition plans > recipes and at the moment i dont have any ideas how to solve this problem with wordpress and acf.

At the moment the user can select his recipes and create a new "private" nutrition plan. But now i want to save the id's of his selected recipes to a acf repeater field.

So far thats all i have:

```
$new_post = array(
        'post_title'    =>   $title,
        'post_content'  =>   $description,
        'post_category' =>   array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'tags_input'    =>   array($tags),
        'post_status'   =>   'private',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
        'post_type'     =>   'ernaehrungsplan'    //'post',page' or use a custom post type if you want to
    );

    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

At this point i stuck a little bit because the update_field() method is only for existing posts? right? Maybe someone can help me :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have inserted the post your $pid variable should contain the ID of the post, which you can use calling update_field()